# A proposition about closed graph of a bounded linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

Let $E$ be a normed space and $T: D\rightarrow E_1$ be a bounded linear operator, where $D\subset E$ is the domain of $T$ and $E_1$ is a normed space. If the graph of $T$ is closed, then $D$ is closed.

I can only prove that $D$ is closed when $E_1$ is a Banach space. But I am not sure whether the original proposition is true or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity mapping from $D$ to $E_1=D$ has a closed graph but $D$ might not be closed.

Comment: $E$ is not equal to $E_1$

Comment: The expression $E_1=D$ was meant to *define* $E_1$.  To be more precise, take any proper dense set $D$ of a normed space $E$, define $E_1:=D$, and consider $T$ to be the identity defined on $D$.  This is the conter-example I meant.